# MVC 4 WebGrid edit row with a button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I have a webgrid, what I want to do is to edit the selected row, but I want this action to be performed when the user press a button and not only when the user select the row. How can I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented something similar recently, the following article helped me: http://stick2basic.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/inline-editing-with-the-webgrid-in-asp-net-mvc-4/

Comment: Thankyou, that solution is goood, but Im trying to put the button edit outside the grid, do you know how to do it?

Comment: Why in the post the author did `var UserID = tr.find("#UserID").html();` instead of `var UserID = tr.find("#UserID").val();`?

Answer (score 1):

```
grid.Column("Action", format: @<text>
                <button class="edit-user display-mode" >Edit</button>
                <button class="save-user edit-mode"  >Save</button>
                <button class="cancel-user edit-mode" >Cancel</button>
                </text>,  style: "col3Width" , canSort: false)
```

Delete these lines and put into seperate div in coding part

Comment: this worked, but how to pass parameter on clicking any button??